# dynamically set length of an input type textbox in jquery or javacscript

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Get maximum 13 numbers in an input type text box but if user presses 14 number as decimal, only then it should allow maximum 16 numbers.**

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" maxlength="15" onkeyup="checkCurrency(this)"/>
```

**script:**

```
    function checkCurrency(ctrl) {
        ctrl.setAttribute('maxlength', '16');
        var currency = ctrl.value.replace(/[,]+/g, '');
        var valid = /^\d{0,13}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(currency),
        val = currency;
        if (valid) {                
            ctrl = val;
        } else {             
            ctrl.setAttribute('maxlength', '13');                
        }
    };
```

Now, it works fine when 14th place is a decimal(.),but please put any integer on 14th place and see the difference.

Comment: I've seen this type of question on SO just today>>>

Comment: your code is working what else do u want

Comment: not working means - when 14th place is an integer then it shows the 14th value and then it is trimmed so it looks like a blink.

Comment: @C-link , this type of Ununderstandable Question?

Comment: yes but solution with jquery

Comment: @C-link:- I am ok with jquery no issues.

Comment: @C-link jQuery is next to redundant when working with string manipulation and attributes.

Comment: @Shivam Sorry, I was trying to find but couldn't.

Comment: check my updated answer, i hope it will help u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

HTML

```
<input id="a" type="text" maxlength="15" />
```

JS

```
$('#a').keypress(function (event) {
      if ($('#a').val().length < 14) {
          if (event.keyCode != '110' && event.charCode != '46') {
              $('#a').attr('maxlength', '13');
          } else if (event.keyCode == '110' || event.charCode == '46') {
              $('#a').attr('maxlength', '16');
          } 
      }
});
```

Comment: @Shivam :anytime budy..:)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just convert the number to a string, check the length and last substring for a period, and adjust the maxlength accordingly

```
function checkCurrency(ctrl) {
    var x = ctrl.value.toString();
    var size = x.length;
    if (x.substring(size-1) == "." && size >= 14) {
        ctrl.maxlength = 16;
    } else {
        ctrl.maxlength = 13;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well did you try to understand it or did you just copy and paste?

Comment: ahh let me understand and then try, i just copied and pasted it.

Comment: Just break it down step by step, and feel free to comment if you don't understand something

Comment: Actually when I enter the 14th character or integer in textbox then it's length is calculated as 14, now if you try to remove that 14th value using "substring() or .slice() or .trim()" it is blinking because first the value goes in textbox and then it is removed. So I have to calculate the length of textbox before getting 14th character in textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="13" />
```

And the jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("input").keypress(function(e)
{
    string = $('input').val();
    length = string.length;
    if (length == 13){
        if (e.which == 46){
            $("input").attr('maxlength', 16);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you have any problem let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can Do Something Like This

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="inp">
```

**JQuery**

```
    $('input').attr('maxLength','13').keyup(

     function (){
     if(this.value.contains('.'))
         $(this).attr('maxLength','16');
    else
        $(this).attr('maxLength','13');
    });
```

and dont forget to add JQuery reference.

**EDIT**:
Code edited as you donot want the text to get blinked.

Answer (score 0):

I never think that a string comparison is better than a regular expression test (when it's a number question (absolutely when it's a decimal question)).
I'm fairly experienced with problems on user input, so I always prefer use regular expressions to do exactly this kind of input behavior, because Its performance is always fast, more reliable, and more easy to maintenance.

I made a "input backup" behavior to always back the last valid insertion. So, for your exactly need, here is a complete example (I kept your Regex): [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2DZSd/1/)

#### jQuery Code

```
var varRegex = /^\d{0,13}(\.\d{0,2})?$/;
var varLastValidValue = "";

$(function ()
{
    $('#SpecialInput').keyup(function ()
    {
        if (!varRegex.test($(this).val()))
            $(this).val(varLastValidValue);

        else
            varLastValidValue = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

Different from other answers, my have the advantage to force only 2 decimal numbers (Any where). On the server side, I think it's essential (And I believe that it's why you are putting a limitation on the input. You are reflecting the format of stored data from DataBase, right!?).

Is important note that this code only works (as It is) for 1 input. For multiple inputs in a same page, a simple approach would use elements attribute, or some thing like that to store the "LastValidValue".

(I know that the perfection would be listen the 'onkeydown' event, and block the user input. But It will use a little more advanced code, and I want to make it simple)

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents

HTML

```
<input type="text" maxlength="13"/>
```

JS

```
$('input').keydown(function (event) {
    $(this).data('previous', $(this).val());
    if ((event.keyCode == 110) || (event.keyCode == 190)) {
        $(this).attr('maxlength', 16);
    }
});
$('input').keyup(function (event) {
    if ( ! /^\d{0,13}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test($(this).val())) {
        $(this).val($(this).data('previous'));
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wA9uV/1/)